# Thunderbird mail folders in sidebar

Tags: email, accounts, sidebar

I would like to re-order my 15 accounts with folders that appear in the sidebar in Thunderbird.  You can drop and drop folders, but you can't re-arrange accounts.  Does anybody know how to do that?  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Have a look at [help] and consider editing your post to include helpful tidbits like what version of OS and thunderbird you run. Some people like to see enough details to know that their answers actually going to work for you

Answer (score 2):

One possibility to re-arrange accounts and folders in the sidebar of Thunderbird is provided by a Thunderbird extension: [Manually sort folders 1.1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/manually-sort-folders/?src=ss)

Screenshot (sorry for the German interface here, it also has an English interface):

[image: Thunderbird Screenshot]

Comment: Great.  Two problems here.  First, I don't speak or read German.  Second, I had previously of an old extension that was supposed to do this but it got very poor ratings.  I have seen some posts that give instructions how to do it manually and I have tried them.  They were not detailed enough and they only worked "sort-of."  I do believe that someone could write a good extension for it.

Comment: @reblark It also has an english interface